# Why doesn't Ask Ubuntu use HTTPS?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, https

Why does Ask Ubuntu use plain ol' HTTP?

In this day in age, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be HTTPS.

Isn't this a huge security risk?

---

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They (Stack Exchange developers) are working on it. It's complicated.

Main sites are already usable via HTTPS. Meta sites are not, and will not be until the domain structure is changed. For details, see

- [Untrusted connection when visiting per-site meta over SSL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216384)
- [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116782/)
- [Stackoverflow.com: the road to SSL](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/)

Comment: But I'm getting the same message on the main (non-meta) site as well...

Comment: try using the HTTPS everywhere extension from the EFF. It works fine on the main site, and gets (almost) all of the content on meta over cleanly.

Comment: @gerry you need update your answer, now it's enabled for both main and meta sites.